# Group by 2 categories then take the sum

Tags: python

[image: df.groupby('croho subonderdeel').sum()]

**Above output is from:**

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel').sum()
```

I took the sum of total graduates per category, but I want to do it per column as well. For instance, just receive the output for the first column '2011 MAN'.

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel','2011 MAN').sum()
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No axis named 2011 MAN for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Then I thought maybe instead of grouping twice, I need to take the sum of '2011 MAN'. So I tried:

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel').sum('2011 MAN')
```

Then I receive this error:

```
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can someone explain to me, why both methods which I'm trying are not possible? Maybe I can solve the issue then by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify column in `[]` like:

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel')['2011 MAN'].sum()
```

You can also specify multiple columns:

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel')['2011 MAN', '2012 MAN'].sum()
```

Also if need `2 columns` output add parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel', as_index=False)['2011 MAN'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby('croho subonderdeel')['2011 MAN'].sum().reset_index()
```

---

But if want group by 2 categories (2 columns) add `[]` to `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['croho subonderdeel', 'another col'])['2011 MAN'].sum()
```

---

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'another col':list('efefef'),
                   '2011 MAN':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   '2011 WROUW':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   '2012 MAN':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   '2012 WROUW':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'croho subonderdeel':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   2011 MAN  2011 WROUW  2012 MAN  2012 WROUW another col croho subonderdeel
0         4           7         1           5           e                  a
1         5           8         3           3           f                  a
2         4           9         5           6           e                  a
3         5           4         7           9           f                  b
4         5           2         1           2           e                  b
5         4           3         0           4           f                  b

print(df.groupby('croho subonderdeel')['2011 MAN'].sum())
croho subonderdeel
a    13
b    14
Name: 2011 MAN, dtype: int64

print(df.groupby('croho subonderdeel', as_index=False)['2011 MAN'].sum())
  croho subonderdeel  2011 MAN
0                  a        13
1                  b        14

print(df.groupby('croho subonderdeel')['2011 MAN'].sum().reset_index())
  croho subonderdeel  2011 MAN
0                  a        13
1                  b        14
```

---

```
print(df.groupby('croho subonderdeel')['2011 MAN', '2012 WROUW'].sum())
                    2011 MAN  2012 WROUW
croho subonderdeel                      
a                         13          14
b                         14          15

print(df.groupby('croho subonderdeel', as_index=False)['2011 MAN', '2012 WROUW'].sum())
  croho subonderdeel  2011 MAN  2012 WROUW
0                  a        13          14
1                  b        14          15
```

---

```
print (df.groupby(['croho subonderdeel', 'another col'])['2011 MAN'].sum())
croho subonderdeel  another col
a                   e              8
                    f              5
b                   e              5
                    f              9
Name: 2011 MAN, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby(['croho subonderdeel', 'another col'], as_index=False)['2011 MAN'].sum())
  croho subonderdeel another col  2011 MAN
0                  a           e         8
1                  a           f         5
2                  b           e         5
3                  b           f         9
```

---

```
print (df.groupby(['croho subonderdeel', 'another col']).sum())
                                2011 MAN  2011 WROUW  2012 MAN  2012 WROUW
croho subonderdeel another col                                            
a                  e                   8          16         6          11
                   f                   5           8         3           3
b                  e                   5           2         1           2
                   f                   9           7         7          13

print (df.groupby(['croho subonderdeel', 'another col'], as_index=False).sum())
 croho subonderdeel another col  2011 MAN  2011 WROUW  2012 MAN  2012 WROUW
0                  a           e         8          16         6          11
1                  a           f         5           8         3           3
2                  b           e         5           2         1           2
3                  b           f         9           7         7          13
```

Comment: It works! Why does '2011 MAN' need to be in square brackets, and 'croho subonderdeel' not? 'croho subonderdeel' is a column as well, yet it works if I just put round brackets.

Comment: This is 2 different things - if use 2 columns in `groupby` then group by 2 columns and for specifying columns for aggregation  use `[]` outside `function groupby`.

Comment: you might also want to add `reset_index()` for all cells filled, like SQL.

Comment: Yes, `reset_index()` or `as_index=False` ;)

Comment: I add sample for better explanation.